# Nested Routes in SvelteKit

Tags: navigation, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3

SvelteKit gives me a 404 when I try to navigate to my nested route. My folder structure:

```
/routes/
  /+layout.svelte
  /+page.svelte
  /about/
    /+page.svelte
  /work/
    /+page.svelte
    /item1/
      /+page.svelte
```

In my browser I can navigate to /work, but navigating to /work/item1 throws a 404 error. What could be the reason?

Comment: The reason is that you have not defined a route for /work/item1. You will need to add a route for that in your routes file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating to Svelte 3.52 seemed to solve the problem.